# How to handle Material UI onRowDeselected

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using the Material UI ReactJS Library in my React App and I wish to know when a user selects and deselects a row.

So far, there is `onRowSelected` callback but there is no `onRowDeselected` callback.

How can I perform an action when a user selects and deselects a row.

Here is my code:

```
<DataGrid classes={{
                        row: classes.row
                    }} checkboxSelection {...rows} rows={rows} columns={columns}
                        onRowSelected={(e) => {
                            console.log(`Selected Row = ${e}`);
                            if (!selectedRows.includes(e)) {
                                setSelectedRows(selectedRows => [...selectedRows, e]);
                            }
                        }}
                    />
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try `onRowClick`. That shouldn't matter if the row is already selected or not and you can check inside the callback if the row is already selected or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isSelected` property for identity in case the row is selected or deselected and access the selected row using `data` property.

```
export default function DataGridDemo() {

  const [selectedRows, setSelectedRows] = React.useState([]);

  const handleRowSelection = ({ data, isSelected }) => {
    console.log(`Selected Row`, data, isSelected);
    if (isSelected) {
      setSelectedRows((prev) => [...prev, data]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
      <DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        checkboxSelection
        disableSelectionOnClick
        pageSize={500}
        onRowSelected={handleRowSelection}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

Sample demo - https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-data-grid-forked-mvndp?file=/src/App.js:350-916